# Docker Compose - MySQL - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD

Tags: mysql, docker-compose

Not able to start mysql container using docker-compose.yaml file, when I use '$' sign for the MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD.

I tried with the other special character '@' and it is starting up.

my docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  database:
    container_name: mysql-dev2
    image: mysql:8.0
    volumes:
      - "./data/mysql-dev2:/var/lib/mysql-dev2-docker"
    # restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: mysqldb2
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: Welcome123$
    ports:
      # <Port exposed> : < MySQL Port running inside container>
      - '3307:3306'
    expose:
      # Opens port 3307 on the container
      - '3307'
# Names our volume
volumes:
  mysql-dev2:
```

> ```
> The error which I am getting
>     F:\docker\mysql-dev2>docker-compose up
>     ERROR: Invalid interpolation format for "environment" option in service "database": "Welcome123$"
> ```

If I change the MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD to 'Welcome123@', the mysql instance is started running.

help me on this.

regards,
Mahadevan.G

Comment: Try to escape it as `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'Welcome123$'`

Comment: Yes, I tried 'Welcome123$' as you mentioned, but still getting the same error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can escape the `$` if with a double `$$`:

```
...
environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: mysqldb2
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: Welcome123$$
...
```

Comment: Thanks, Neo. I stored them in a .env file and it is working.

Comment: I'm glad it worked. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers